# Почему в цикле if для проверки вместо Number мы пишем 'number'?

Tags: javascript

```js
let menu = {
  width: 200,
  height: 300,
  title: "My menu"
};

function multiple(obj){
  for(key in obj){
    if(typeof obj[key] == 'number'){ //Почему тут 'number', а не Number?
      obj[key] *= 2;
    }
  }
}

multiple(menu)
console.log(menu);
```

Comment: Потому что оператор `typeof` возвращает **строку** https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Answer (score 0):

В вашем коде вы используете typeof obj[key] == 'number', а не Number(obj[key]), потому что typeof - это оператор JavaScript, который возвращает строку, представляющую тип данных переменной. Он предназначен для определения типа переменной.

Сравнение typeof obj[key] == 'number' проверяет, является ли тип значения, хранящегося в свойстве key объекта obj, равным строке 'number'. Если это условие выполняется, то это означает, что значение в объекте имеет тип number, и код внутри if выполняется.

С другой стороны, Number(obj[key]) - это функция JavaScript Number, которая пытается преобразовать значение obj[key] в числовой тип данных. Если значение obj[key] не может быть корректно преобразовано в число (например, если это не число или строка, которая не является числом), то будет возвращено значение NaN (Not-a-Number).

В вашем случае, чтобы удвоить числовое значение в объекте menu, правильно использовать условие if (typeof obj[key] == 'number'), потому что вы хотите проверить, действительно ли значение является числом, и удвоить его, только если это так.